# Update huge array of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've came across the situation, where I need to select huge amount of data (say 100k records which look like `ID | {"points":"9","votes":"2","breakdown":"0,0,0,1,1"}`), process it in PHP and then put it back. Question is about putting it back efficiently. I saw a solution using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, I saw a solution with `UPDATE` using `CASE`. Are there any other solutions? Which would be the most efficient way to update huge data array?

Comment: How would the user's environment affect the proposed solution?

Comment: your question is not clear....what did you mean by user's server?

Answer (score 0):

Better choice is using simple update.
When you try to put data with insert exceptions your DB will do more additional work: try to insert, verify constraints, raise exception, update row, verify constraints again.

**Update**

Run tests on my local PC for insert into ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and UPDATE statements against the table with 43k rows.

the first approach works on 40% faster.
But both worked faster then 1.5s. I suppose, you php code will be bottleneck of your approach and you should not worry about speed of MySQL statements. Of course, it works if you table not huge and does not had dozens millions rows.

**Update 2**

My local PC uses MySQL 5.6 in default configuration. 
CPU: 8Gb

Comment: I doubt that 100k `UPDATE` queries is the best choice here tbh

Comment: You didn't post the specs of your computer or config variables of your instance, therefore your benchmark isn't really meaningful whatsoever.